# Why is the negation of $A \Rightarrow B$ not $A \Rightarrow \lnot B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

The book I am reading says that the negation of "$A$ implies $B$" is "$A$ does not necessarily imply $B$" and not "$A$ implies not $B$". I understand the distinction between the two cases but why is the first one considered true?

Comment: Because it is possible that $A$ neither implies $B$ nor $\lnot B$, and $P\lor \lnot P$ is always true.

Comment: "A does not necessarily imply B" is vague, so it is not a correct negation either.  It means that if $A$ is true, $B$ might be false.  The correct negation is $A\land \lnot B$.

Comment: You already got an example for this one, but in general with any doubt related to logic, my suggestion is to come up with your own examples, and you should be able to figure it out in most cases.

Comment: @vadim123 The negation of "If I am awake then I am drinking whiskey" is "I am awake and I am not drinking whiskey."  You tacitly added a quantifier: "whenever I am awake..." leading to the negation "there exists a time when I am ..." and the resulting uncertainty that you reported with "might".

Comment: the negations of "does" is "does not". The negation of "implies" is "does not imply". You got a bunch of answers ... many of them throwing truth value tables at you, which for me is of no use. I recommend the answers by Carl Mummert, and Yves Daoust who give suitable examples to explain the "why" part rather than the "what" part.

Comment: I think this question has an unfortunate ambiguity, leading to very disparate answers. Notably, the `propositional-calculus` tag would suggest that $A,B$ are unquantified propositions (closed formulae) but the text of the question, and the use of $\Rightarrow$ rather that $\to$ suggests they could be (implicitly universally qualified) open formula. The answer to the question "could $A\Rightarrow B$ and $A\Rightarrow\lnot B$ both fail to be true?" will depend on the point of view. And the proper answer to the actual question above could as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more intuitive explanation. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are unrelated. For example, $A$ could be "France is a country in Europe" and $B$ could be "I will win the lottery". It is certainly the case that we know $A$ does not imply $B$ for these sentences: knowing that France is in Europe tells me nothing about the future! But we also do not know that $A \Rightarrow \lnot B$, for the same reason.

So in this case, we only know that $A \not  \Rightarrow B$.  This shows there is a difference between $A \not  \Rightarrow B$ (which just says that $A$ does not imply $B$) and $A  \Rightarrow \lnot B$ (which says $A$ does imply the negation of $B$).

This kind of intuition is important when you move from propositional logic to more general mathematics. For example, suppose we are looking at natural numbers. Let $A$ say "$x$ is an even natural number" and let $B$ say "$x$ is a natural number that is a multiple of $6$". Neither $A$ nor $B$ is true or false on its own, because the $x$ has no fixed value. Sometimes $A$ is true and sometimes it is false. But we still have that $A \not \Rightarrow B$ (e.g., $2$ is even but not a multiple of 6) and $B \Rightarrow A$ (because every multiple of 6 is even). We also do not have $A \Rightarrow \lnot B$ (because some even numbers are multiples of 6).

Rather than trying to analyze this more complicated kind of implication in terms of truth values, it is helpful to develop the right intuition: $A \Rightarrow B$ says that knowing $A$ alone is enough to know $B$. From that intuition, you can work out the formalities involving truth values, but more importantly you can *do mathematics* from that intuition.

Comment: But "knowing" that France is not in Europe also tells me nothing about the future, and yet "France is not in Europe" *does* imply "I will win the lottery" because implications from false statements are always true.

Comment: @celtschk: On one hand, I was looking for an intuitive explanation (although I did choose $A$ to be true to formally avoid this issue).  But the reduction of $A$ and $B$ to truth values is also somewhat misleading; in many settings implications are about more than truth values (e.g. when $A$ and $B$ have free variables, or in nonclassical settings where there are no truth values). I think it's helpful for students to also develop their intuitive sense of what $A \Rightarrow B$ *means*: it means that the knowledge that $A$ holds is enough to guarantee that $B$ holds.

Comment: I believe you are conflating $\vdash$ with $\implies$.  And although as a trained mathematician you may know the difference, the OP probably does not.  Two statements being unrelated makes $\vdash$ false, but not $\implies$, which is simply a statement of "state".  Intuition is good, but this intuitive conceptualization isn't correct.

Comment: @DanielV: implication is much more than just the logical connective used to model it in propositional logic. Once someone has a good intuition for how implication works, I think they will have less confusion about the logical connective as well. (In some sense, the logical connective $\lnot A \lor B$, the logical implication connective $\vDash$, and the provability connective $\vdash$ all have implication-like aspects, but that is too far removed from the simple intuition about "$A$ implies $B$" for this answer).

Comment: Also, in my first example, I deliberately chose a $B$ that does not have a well-defined truth value (because it is about the future).  So the implication there cannot be easily replaced by a tuth-functional connective.

Comment: I refuse to acknowledge the Frankish claims over Gallia!!!

Comment: I think the example is particularly ill chosen. Although $A\to\lnot B$ is not the negation of $A\to B$, is it in fact that case that $(A\to B)\lor(A\to\lnot B)$ is (in classical logic) a tautology (for any $A<B$, not just for the ones chosen here) by the same token that $B\lor\lnot B$ is a tautology (and of course $\lnot B$ _is_ the negation of $B$). The reason that $A\to\lnot B$ is not the negation of $A\to B$ is because _both_ could be true simultaneously (whenever $A$ is false), not because both could simultaneously fail to be true.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen :  you have a good point: there are two arguments for why $A \Rightarrow \lnot B$ is not the negation of $A \Rightarrow B$. First, both could be true. Second, both could be false. I wanted to write here about the second, which is related to the intuitive meaning of implication. The other answers that look at truth values do a fine job for the first reason. But the treatment of $\Rightarrow$ only in terms of truth values can disguise the underlying intuition about the informal idea of "implication". (Perhaps I also took more note of the word "necessarily" in the question).

Comment: "A⇒B says that knowing A alone is enough to know B."

Yikes!  What if detachment isn't a rule of inference?  How does knowing "A" end up as enough to know B in such a case?

Also, even if we have detachment as a rule of inference, if Epq is true also, then it seems fair to say that knowing "p" alone is enough to know "q" also.  However, Epq is definitely different from Cpq.

Alright, I guess if detachment is a rule of inference, and it is not presumed that knowing B is enough to know A, then A $\rightarrow$ B says that knowing A is enough to know B.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this simple example:
$$x>0\Rightarrow x>1.$$
This is clearly a false statement.

Among the next two ones, which is true ?
$$x>0\nRightarrow x>1$$
$$x>0\Rightarrow x\le1?$$

Comment: This implicitly has a $\forall x$ in front of it, so in fact neither of the last two statements are true, unless you quantify them existentially, in which case they are both true.  I think an example for this problem should have the root operation be implication, not quantification.

Comment: @DanielV: ha-ha.

Answer (score 4):

$ \newcommand{\T} {\text{True}}
 \newcommand{\F} {\text{False}}$

$$\begin{array} {cc|cc}
A & B & A \implies \lnot B & A \not \implies B \\ \hline
\T & \T & \F & \F \\
\T & \F & \T & \T \\
\F & \T & \T & \F \\
\F & \F & \T & \F \\
\end{array}$$

So in fact for material implication, $A \implies \lnot B$ and $A \not \implies B$ are the same except for when $A$ is false.  This makes it possible to construct a counter example:

True statement $A \implies B$:

> If you are an alien, then you have not posted on math.se.

That is a true statement, because the qualifying phrase is false.

Incorrect negation: $A \implies \lnot B$

> If you are an alien, then you have posted on math.se.

The qualifying phrase is still unchanged and so false, so the statement is true, so it is not a negation of the original statement.

Correct negation $A \not \implies B$:

> You are an alien and you have posted on math.se.

That statement is (regrettably) false.  That is because it is the negation of the original statement.

Comment: It's annoying how the negated implication sign looks ridiculous isn't it?

Comment: @MagicMan At least it's unambiguous.  There are enough annoying notations in mathematics that I don't even notice the negated implication typography.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it's so "unambiguous"--since the slash through starts at the very beginning of the arrow. It just looks very odd. Something like $\nrightarrow$ is far better IMO or $\nRightarrow$. But the MathJax vs. LaTeX rendering is always an interesting issue in terms of what renders and what doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume you are familiar with two equivalences (if not, then simply write up truth tables to verify them): 
$$
A\to B\equiv\neg A\lor B\quad(1)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\neg(A\lor B)\equiv\neg A\land\neg B\quad(2).
$$

---

**Why your book is right:** We can negate *anything* by simply tacking on "it is not the case that...," and this is basically what your authors have done. More specifically: "The negation of '$A$ implies $B$' is '**It is not the case** that $A$ implies $B$'." Of course, simply saying "it is not the case" is hardly useful. *That* is why what your textbook authors are saying is correct, but what they are saying is not very meaningful (i.e., they don't give you any sense of what the negation of "$A$ implies $B$" actually means in any useful way).

---

**Why you are wrong:** Let's consider what the negation of $A\to B$ and $A\to\neg B$ are equivalent to by reducing them to easily understandable statements using $(1)$ and $(2)$. Doing this will show why your intuition is off-base.

For the negation of $A\to B$, we have the following:
$$
\neg(A\to B)\equiv\underbrace{\neg(\neg A\lor B)}_{\text{used $(1)$}}\equiv \underbrace{A\land\neg B}_{\text{used $(2)$}}.
$$
For $A\to\neg B$, we have the following:
$$
A\to\neg B\equiv\underbrace{\neg A\lor\neg B)}_{\text{used $(1)$}}.
$$
It should be fairly clear now that
$$
\neg(A\to B)\equiv A\land\neg B\not\equiv\neg A\lor\neg B\equiv A\to\neg B,
$$
but to further clarify, consider what happens when $A$ is false and $B$ is true. We would have that $A\land\neg B$ is **false** while $\neg A\lor\neg B$ is **true**, contradicting the thought that they are equivalent.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: This doesn't explain things.  Suppose that (1) is False, as say it is in Lukasiewicz 3-valued logic.  It still holds that NCab and CaNb differ.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The OP is obviously not using whatever kind of logic it is you mentioned. Hardly deserves a downvotes. Based on the question history of the OP, I'd imagine the OP is just learning some basic mathematical logic. And my explanation is fine--it condenses the original problem down into statements forms where there's a clear counter example like I gave. No one else had a problem with my explanation. You seem to be the only one to take issue.

Comment: "The OP is obviously not using whatever kind of logic it is you mentioned."

Syntactically speaking the logic he is using probably is the same as Lukasiewicz 3-valued logic in that the formation rules are the same.  You've tried to explain things here semantically, but the issue here is purely syntactical in terms of formation rules (and in truth semantics doesn't always explain much ... not all tautologies have the same power).  To get the negation of something, we first have to have the entire wff.  Then we negate it.  (A$\rightarrow$$\lnot$B) doesn't negate the conditional, it negates "B".

Answer (score 1):

A implies B is logically equivalent to (not A or B ). And its negation by De Morgan's law is simply (A and not B). You may write it's truth table to see it.

The only way an implication will fail to hold is if it's hypothesis is true but conclusion is false. This is simply (A and not B). If you negate it you will get (not A or B) which is then logically equivalent to A implies B.

Answer (score 1):

For a sentence $\phi$, its negation $\neg\phi$ is the sentence that is true exactly when $\phi$ is false. If $A$ is false, then both $A\Rightarrow B$ and $A\Rightarrow\neg B$ are true, so they aren't negations. But on the other hand, $A\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to "$\neg A$ or $B$". The negation of this is "$A$ and $\neg B$", which means that $A$ can be true and $B$ can be false. So $A$ doesn't necessarily imply $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Definition: $A\implies B \equiv \neg[A \land \neg B]$.

Taking the negation, $\neg[A\implies B] \equiv A \land \neg B$.

By definition, we also have $A\implies \neg B \equiv  \neg[A \land B]$.

Now, $A\land \neg B \not\equiv \neg [A \land B]$

Therefore, $\neg[A\implies B]\not\equiv A\implies \neg B$.

Answer (score 1):

If the negation of $A\implies B$ were $A \implies \lnot B$, then they would have to have the opposite truth values for all valuations of $A$ and $B$. So let's just check that:
$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
A & B & A\implies B & A\implies\lnot B \\\hline
\text{False} & \text{False} & \text{True}  & \color{red}{\text{True}} \\
\text{False} & \text{True}  & \text{True}  & \color{red}{\text{True}} \\
\text{True}  & \text{False} & \text{False} & \text{True} \\
\text{True}  & \text{True}  & \text{True}  & \text{False}
\end{array}$$
As you see, whenever $A$ is false, $A\implies\lnot B$ has not the opposite truth value of $A\implies B$, therefore it cannot be its negation.

Answer (score -1):

Try building both $\lnot$(A$\rightarrow$B) and (A$\rightarrow$$\lnot$B) up from their component well-formed formulas.  Or write them in a prefix notation like the following:

$\lnot$($\rightarrow$(A, B)) and

$\rightarrow$(A, $\lnot$(B))

In the former we have "A" and "B" and then a conditional.  Then we negate the conditional.

In the latter we have "A" and "B", *then B gets negated*, and finally we have a conditional.

This sentence " the negation of "A implies B" is "A does not necessarily imply B"" gets considered true, because "not necessarily" applies to "imply", it does NOT apply to B.